# there is a "Cannot find module rxjs/websocket" error after "npm install"

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

there was an error, `"Cannot find module rxjs/websocket"`
when I ran "`npm i`"

i tried "`npm i --save rxjs-websocekts`" and `rxjs-websocekts@6`
but nothing solving
and search about this an error
but I can not find the solutions.

**ionic info**

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.2.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.6
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.3

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.2.0, (and 15other plugins)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/root/Android/Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v6.5.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 3.10.3
   OS                : Linux 4.15
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "bm_client",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ios": "ionic cordova run ios -- --buildFlag='-UseModernBuildSystem=0'"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/android-permissions": "4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/calendar": "4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "4.3.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/facebook": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/fcm": "4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase": "4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/mobile-accessibility": "4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/photo-viewer": "4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/wheel-selector": "4.16.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "2.0.1",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.118",
    "@types/node": "10.12.2",
    "@ultimate/ngxerrors": "1.4.0",
    "add": "2.0.6",
    "angular-progress-bar": "1.0.8",
    "angular2-highcharts": "0.5.5",
    "angular2-signaturepad": "2.8.0",
    "angularfire2": "5.0.1",
    "build": "0.1.4",
    "chart.js": "2.7.3",
    "com-sarriaroman-photoviewer": "1.2.2",
    "cordova": "8.1.2",
    "cordova-android": "~7.1.4",
    "cordova-browser": "5.0.4",
    "cordova-ios": "4.5.5",
    "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "4.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": "2.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ios-camera-permissions": "1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-iroot": "0.8.0",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "git+https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information.git",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.3",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "2.5.0",
    "cordova-wheel-selector-plugin": "1.1.2",
    "date-fns": "1.29.0",
    "firebase": "5.4.2",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.6",
    "ionic-long-press": "1.5.0",
    "ionic2-calendar": "0.4.5",
    "ionic3-calendar-en": "1.1.3",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "js-sha256": "0.9.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.11",
    "moment": "2.22.2",
    "ng-circle-progress": "1.0.0",
    "ng2-charts": "1.6.0",
    "phonegap-plugin-mobile-accessibility": "1.0.5",
    "phonegap-plugin-multidex": "1.0.0",
    "plugin": "0.3.3",
    "rxjs": "6.3.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.0.0-tactical-rc.1",
    "slide-ruler": "1.1.1",
    "socket.io-client": "2.2.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.4",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.3",
    "@ionic/lab": "1.0.8",
    "typescript": "2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-wheel-selector-plugin": {},
      "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
        "APP_ID": "272085810142209",
        "APP_NAME": "bodymanager",
        "FACEBOOK_HYBRID_APP_EVENTS": "false",
        "FACEBOOK_ANDROID_SDK_VERSION": "4.40.0"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {},
      "phonegap-plugin-mobile-accessibility": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {
        "CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "default",
        "PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "default"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ios-camera-permissions": {
        "CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "default",
        "PHOTOLIBRARY_ADD_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "default",
        "PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "default",
        "MICROPHONE_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app needs microphone access"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-iroot": {
        "ENABLE_BUSYBOX_CHECK": "true"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": {},
      "com-sarriaroman-photoviewer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "browser",
      "ios",
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

**when running "`npm install`"**

```
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@5.2.11
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@5.2.11
├── @ionic-native/calendar@4.18.0
├── @ionic-native/camera@4.3.3
├── @ionic-native/core@4.12.0
├── @ionic-native/device@4.17.0
├── @ionic-native/facebook@4.7.0
├── @ionic-native/splash-screen@4.12.0
├── @ionic-native/status-bar@4.12.0
├── @ionic-native/wheel-selector@4.16.0
├── @types/node@10.12.2
├── angular-progress-bar@1.0.8
├─┬ angularfire2@5.0.1
│ ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@^6.0.0
│ ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@^6.0.0
│ ├── @angular/fire@5.0.0
│ ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser@^6.0.0
│ └── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@^6.0.0
├── chart.js@2.7.3
├─┬ cordova-sqlite-storage@2.5.0
│ └── cordova-sqlite-storage-dependencies@1.2.0
├── cordova-wheel-selector-plugin@1.1.2
├── date-fns@1.29.0
├─┬ firebase@5.4.2
│ ├─┬ @firebase/app@0.3.3
│ │ ├── @firebase/app-types@0.3.2
│ │ ├─┬ @firebase/util@0.2.1
│ │ │ └── tslib@1.9.0
│ │ └── tslib@1.9.0
│ ├─┬ @firebase/auth@0.7.4
│ │ └── @firebase/auth-types@0.3.4
│ ├─┬ @firebase/database@0.3.4
│ │ ├── @firebase/database-types@0.3.2
│ │ ├── @firebase/logger@0.1.1
│ │ └── tslib@1.9.0
│ ├─┬ @firebase/firestore@0.7.2
│ │ ├── @firebase/firestore-types@0.6.0
│ │ ├── @firebase/webchannel-wrapper@0.2.8
│ │ ├─┬ grpc@1.13.1
│ │ │ └─┬ node-pre-gyp@0.10.3
│ │ │   ├── detect-libc@1.0.3
│ │ │   ├─┬ mkdirp@0.5.1
│ │ │   │ └── minimist@0.0.8
│ │ │   ├─┬ needle@2.2.1
│ │ │   │ ├─┬ debug@2.6.9
│ │ │   │ │ └── ms@2.0.0
│ │ │   │ ├─┬ iconv-lite@0.4.23
│ │ │   │ │ └── safer-buffer@2.1.2
│ │ │   │ └── sax@1.2.4
│ │ │   ├─┬ nopt@4.0.1
│ │ │   │ ├── abbrev@1.1.1
│ │ │   │ └─┬ osenv@0.1.5
│ │ │   │   ├── os-homedir@1.0.2
│ │ │   │   └── os-tmpdir@1.0.2
│ │ │   ├─┬ npm-packlist@1.1.11
│ │ │   │ ├─┬ ignore-walk@3.0.1
│ │ │   │ │ └─┬ minimatch@3.0.4
│ │ │   │ │   └─┬ brace-expansion@1.1.11
│ │ │   │ │     ├── balanced-match@1.0.0
│ │ │   │ │     └── concat-map@0.0.1
│ │ │   │ └── npm-bundled@1.0.3
│ │ │   ├─┬ npmlog@4.1.2
│ │ │   │ ├─┬ are-we-there-yet@1.1.5
│ │ │   │ │ ├── delegates@1.0.0
│ │ │   │ │ └─┬ readable-stream@2.3.6
│ │ │   │ │   ├── core-util-is@1.0.2
│ │ │   │ │   ├── isarray@1.0.0
│ │ │   │ │   ├── process-nextick-args@2.0.0
│ │ │   │ │   ├── string_decoder@1.1.1
│ │ │   │ │   └── util-deprecate@1.0.2
│ │ │   │ ├── console-control-strings@1.1.0
│ │ │   │ ├─┬ gauge@2.7.4
│ │ │   │ │ ├── aproba@1.2.0
│ │ │   │ │ ├── has-unicode@2.0.1
│ │ │   │ │ ├── object-assign@4.1.1
│ │ │   │ │ ├── signal-exit@3.0.2
│ │ │   │ │ ├─┬ string-width@1.0.2
│ │ │   │ │ │ ├── code-point-at@1.1.0
│ │ │   │ │ │ └─┬ is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0
│ │ │   │ │ │   └── number-is-nan@1.0.1
│ │ │   │ │ ├─┬ strip-ansi@3.0.1
│ │ │   │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.1.1
│ │ │   │ │ └── wide-align@1.1.3
│ │ │   │ └── set-blocking@2.0.0
│ │ │   ├─┬ rc@1.2.8
│ │ │   │ ├── deep-extend@0.6.0
│ │ │   │ ├── ini@1.3.5
│ │ │   │ ├── minimist@1.2.0
│ │ │   │ └── strip-json-comments@2.0.1
│ │ │   ├─┬ rimraf@2.6.2
│ │ │   │ └─┬ glob@7.1.2
│ │ │   │   ├── fs.realpath@1.0.0
│ │ │   │   ├─┬ inflight@1.0.6
│ │ │   │   │ └── wrappy@1.0.2
│ │ │   │   ├── inherits@2.0.3
│ │ │   │   ├── once@1.4.0
│ │ │   │   └── path-is-absolute@1.0.1
│ │ │   ├── semver@5.5.0
│ │ │   └─┬ tar@4.4.4
│ │ │     ├── chownr@1.0.1
│ │ │     ├── fs-minipass@1.2.5
│ │ │     ├── minipass@2.3.3
│ │ │     ├── minizlib@1.1.0
│ │ │     ├── safe-buffer@5.1.2
│ │ │     └── yallist@3.0.2
│ │ └── tslib@1.9.0
│ ├─┬ @firebase/functions@0.3.0
│ │ ├── @firebase/functions-types@0.2.0
│ │ ├── @firebase/messaging-types@0.2.3
│ │ └── tslib@1.9.0
│ ├─┬ @firebase/messaging@0.3.5
│ │ └── tslib@1.9.0
│ ├─┬ @firebase/polyfill@0.3.3
│ │ ├── core-js@2.5.5
│ │ └── promise-polyfill@7.1.2
│ └─┬ @firebase/storage@0.2.3
│   ├── @firebase/storage-types@0.2.3
│   └── tslib@1.9.0
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY ionic-angular@3.9.6
├── ionic2-calendar@0.4.5
├── moment@2.22.2
├── ng-circle-progress@1.0.0
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@6.3.2
├── rxjs-compat@6.0.0-tactical-rc.1
└── webpack-merge@4.1.4
```

and then there was an error,

> "Uncaught Error: Cannnot find module "rxjs/websocket."

I've never used the "`rxjs/websocket`" module.
this an error suddenly appeared.

what should I remove or add for this error?

Thank you in advance

**when I tried "`npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save`" and then
ran serve**
above errors

```
[app-scripts] [19:10:36]  ionic-app-scripts 3.2.3
[app-scripts] [19:10:36]  watch started ...
[app-scripts] [19:10:36]  build dev started ...
[app-scripts] [19:10:36]  clean started ...
[app-scripts] [19:10:36]  clean finished in 8 ms
[app-scripts] [19:10:36]  copy started ...
[app-scripts] [19:10:36]  deeplinks started ...
[app-scripts] [19:10:36]  deeplinks finished in 419 ms
[app-scripts] [19:10:36]  transpile started ...
[app-scripts] [19:10:41]  typescript: node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts, line: 81
[app-scripts] [19:10:41]  typescript: node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts, line: 81
[app-scripts] [19:10:41]  typescript: node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts, line: 81
[app-scripts] [19:10:41]  typescript: node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts, line: 82
[app-scripts] [19:10:41]  typescript: node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts, line: 82
[app-scripts] [19:10:41]  typescript: node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts, line: 82
[app-scripts] [19:10:41]  typescript: node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts, line: 81
[app-scripts] [19:10:41]  typescript: node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts, line: 81
[app-scripts] [19:10:41]  typescript: node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts, line: 81
[app-scripts] [19:10:41]  typescript: node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts, line: 81
[app-scripts] [19:10:41]  typescript: node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts, line: 81
[app-scripts] [19:10:41]  typescript: node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts, line: 82
[app-scripts] [19:10:41]  typescript: node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts, line: 82
[app-scripts] [19:10:41]  typescript: node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts, line: 82
[app-scripts] [19:10:41]  typescript: node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts, line: 82
[app-scripts] [19:10:41]  typescript: node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts, line: 82
[app-scripts]             ';' expected.
[app-scripts]       L81:  export declare type ObservedValueOf<O> = O extends ObservableInput<infer T> ? T :never;
[app-scripts]       L82:  export declare type ObservedValuesFromArray<X> = X extends Array<ObservableInput<infer T>> ? T : never;
[app-scripts]             ';' expected.
[app-scripts]       L81:  export declare type ObservedValueOf<O> = O extends ObservableInput<infer T> ? T :never;
[app-scripts]       L82:  export declare type ObservedValuesFromArray<X> = X extends Array<ObservableInput<infer T>> ? T : never;
[app-scripts]             Expression expected.
[app-scripts]       L81:  export declare type ObservedValueOf<O> = O extends ObservableInput<infer T> ? T :never;
[app-scripts]       L82:  export declare type ObservedValuesFromArray<X> = X extends Array<ObservableInput<infer T>> ? T : never;
[app-scripts]             ';' expected.
[app-scripts]       L81:  export declare type ObservedValueOf<O> = O extends ObservableInput<infer T> ? T :never;
[app-scripts]       L82:  export declare type ObservedValuesFromArray<X> = X extends Array<ObservableInput<infer T>> ? T : never;
[app-scripts]             ';' expected.
[app-scripts]       L81:  export declare type ObservedValueOf<O> = O extends ObservableInput<infer T> ? T :never;
[app-scripts]       L82:  export declare type ObservedValuesFromArray<X> = X extends Array<ObservableInput<infer T>> ? T : never;
[app-scripts]             Expression expected.
[app-scripts]       L81:  export declare type ObservedValueOf<O> = O extends ObservableInput<infer T> ? T :never;
[app-scripts]       L82:  export declare type ObservedValuesFromArray<X> = X extends Array<ObservableInput<infer T>> ? T : never;
[app-scripts]             'ObservableInput' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
[app-scripts]       L81:  export declare type ObservedValueOf<O> = O extends ObservableInput<infer T> ? T :never;
[app-scripts]       L82:  export declare type ObservedValuesFromArray<X> = X extends Array<ObservableInput<infer T>> ? T : never;
[app-scripts]             Cannot find name 'infer'.
[app-scripts]       L81:  export declare type ObservedValueOf<O> = O extends ObservableInput<infer T> ? T :never;
[app-scripts]       L82:  export declare type ObservedValuesFromArray<X> = X extends Array<ObservableInput<infer T>> ? T : never;
[app-scripts]             Cannot find name 'T'.
[app-scripts]       L81:  export declare type ObservedValueOf<O> = O extends ObservableInput<infer T> ? T :never;
[app-scripts]       L82:  export declare type ObservedValuesFromArray<X> = X extends Array<ObservableInput<infer T>> ? T : never;
[app-scripts]             Cannot find name 'T'.
[app-scripts]       L81:  export declare type ObservedValueOf<O> = O extends ObservableInput<infer T> ? T :never;
[app-scripts]       L82:  export declare type ObservedValuesFromArray<X> = X extends Array<ObservableInput<infer T>> ? T : never;
[app-scripts]             'never' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
[app-scripts]       L81:  export declare type ObservedValueOf<O> = O extends ObservableInput<infer T> ? T :never;
[app-scripts]       L82:  export declare type ObservedValuesFromArray<X> = X extends Array<ObservableInput<infer T>> ? T : never;
[app-scripts]             'ObservableInput' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
[app-scripts]       L81:  export declare type ObservedValueOf<O> = O extends ObservableInput<infer T> ? T :never;
[app-scripts]       L82:  export declare type ObservedValuesFromArray<X> = X extends Array<ObservableInput<infer T>> ? T : never;
[app-scripts]             Cannot find name 'infer'.
[app-scripts]       L81:  export declare type ObservedValueOf<O> = O extends ObservableInput<infer T> ? T :never;
[app-scripts]       L82:  export declare type ObservedValuesFromArray<X> = X extends Array<ObservableInput<infer T>> ? T : never;
[app-scripts]             Cannot find name 'T'.
[app-scripts]       L81:  export declare type ObservedValueOf<O> = O extends ObservableInput<infer T> ? T :never;
[app-scripts]       L82:  export declare type ObservedValuesFromArray<X> = X extends Array<ObservableInput<infer T>> ? T : never;
[app-scripts]             Cannot find name 'T'.
[app-scripts]       L81:  export declare type ObservedValueOf<O> = O extends ObservableInput<infer T> ? T :never;
[app-scripts]       L82:  export declare type ObservedValuesFromArray<X> = X extends Array<ObservableInput<infer T>> ? T : never;
[app-scripts]             'never' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
[app-scripts]       L81:  export declare type ObservedValueOf<O> = O extends ObservableInput<infer T> ? T :never;
[app-scripts]       L82:  export declare type ObservedValuesFromArray<X> = X extends Array<ObservableInput<infer T>> ? T : never;
```

Answer (score 1):

try installing `rxjs@6` and `rxjs-compat@6`

> npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save

Comment: Sorry i don't know comment a lot of errors :(
so I edited my question.
Please check my edited post

Answer (score 0):

Your code or some other module is using rxjs/websocket. There is a solution mentioned on github.

https://github.com/stbui/angular-material-app/issues/39https://github.com/stbui/angular-material-app/issues/39

Comment: thanks for the answer
I don't import "rxjs/websocket" anywhere

Comment: is there any dependent module which is using it. and try not to use rxjs-compat

Comment: how can i do?
I've annotated all the rxjs we use
but still issue